# What is the reason for this UITableView not showing up on my view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a second view controller (not my main one), "ShowCommunities" I have a TableView which is to be populated with data from an API call.

The table isn't showing up at all.

I have put a `print` command inside the function that counts how many rows there are and it is reporting none.

I have printed the output of my API call and that returns the following:

> names:  [Optional("Steve Jones"), Optional("Brad Walker")]

I have copied the same functions and set up that I used for a previous table on my main view controller, "View Controller" and I am not getting any errors...

But I am obviously missing something.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ShowCommunityViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var membersTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var communityName: UILabel!
var communityIsCalled: String?
var comIds =  [String]()
var communityId: Int?

var communityPlayerIds =  [String]()
var selectedCellTitle: String?
var cellId: Int?

var communityPlayers =  [String?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    communityName.text = communityIsCalled
    self.membersTableView.delegate = self
    self.membersTableView.dataSource = self
    membersTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print (self.communityPlayers.count)
    return self.communityPlayers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let title = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedCellTitle = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    cellId = indexPath.row
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "id=\(comIds[communityId!])";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                  if let arr = json?["players"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.communityPlayerIds = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}
                        self.communityPlayers = arr.flatMap { $0["user_name"]!}

                       print ("names: ",self.communityPlayers)
                    }

                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
        }
    task.resume()
    membersTableView.reloadData()

}

}
```

I am not even getting an blank cells.

The `print (self.communityPlayers.count)` command outputs:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0

Any ideas?

Comment: you have not uploaded your table-view after you fetched the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put membersTableView.reloadData() inside DispatchQueue.main.async 
after self.communityPlayers get assigned

Comment: Great stuff! That's fixed it.  So why does membersTableView.reloadData() have to be inside, and not work outside?  I just figured once that block of code has executed the code will continue and run the membersTableView.reloadData() after task.resum()

Comment: of course because async block get executed later ... (accepting the answer would be fair :)

Comment: I have to wait another 1 min :)

Comment: one other thing - there is a slight delay in the table being populated, and the print (self.communityPlayers.count) now outputs 0 0 0 0 2..   I take it the delay is the 4x 0's.  Is the anything I can do about this?

Comment: add an some kind of UIActivityIndicator until data are available makes the UX better